# Update objects with values of a different model joined by multiple columns with additional filtering on their FKs using Django ORM

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Here is what my models look like:

```
EntryGroup(models.Model):
  ...

EntrySource(models.Model):
  entry_group = FK(EntryGroup)
  ...

Entry(models.Model):
  entry_group = FK(EntryGroup)
  ...

EntryItem(models.Model):
  entry = FK(Entry)
  attribute_1 = ...
  attribute_2 = ...
  ...

EntryItemCandidate(models.Model):
  entry_source = FK(EntrySource)
  attribute_1 = ...
  attribute_2 = ...
  existing_entry_item = FK(EntryItem, null=True)
  ...
```

I am trying to achieve the following functionality:

Get all the objects from model EntryItemCandidate with specified field entry_source_id (FK EntrySource), and update their exitsting_entry_item field with id of object EntryItem that meets following criteria:

1. EntryItem has the same values of fields attribute_1 and attribute_2 as EntryItemCandidate
2. EntryItem's Entry has the same value of field entry_group (FK EntryGroup) as EntryItemCandidate's EntrySource field entry_group (FK EntryGroup)
3. If there is no EntryItem meeting these criteria, exitsting_entry_item should be set to Null.

I used to perform this operation iterating for each EntryItemCandidate, but it was way to slow (it would execute order of 10000s queries for each task).

I then managed to perform this operation using SQL:

```
update entry_item_caindidate
set
  entry_item_candidate.existing_entry_item = entry_item.id
from 
  entry_item_candidate
  inner join entry_item on 
    entry_item_candidate.attribute_1 = entry_item.attribute_1
    and entry_item_candidate.attribute_2 = entry_item.attribute_2
  inner join entry on entry.id = entry_item.entry_id
  inner join entry_source on entry_source.id = entry_candidate.entry_source_id
where
  entry_source.entry_group_id = entry.entry_group_id
  and entry_item_candidate.entry_source_id = {param}
```

But since I am expecting to move between multiple database engines I wanted use pure QuerySets without iteration (query above won't work on sqlite, but works on MSSQL due to UPDATE ... FROM clause).

Is this possible?